# bash, Regular expression to stop at first match

Tags: regex, sed

My string is:

```
sdk_version=ios4.2.4&gender=male&product=JE779SPAKLZ5SGAMZ&shop_country=sg&user_id=44337&app_version=1.5.1
```

in this case 'product' is before 'user_id' but sometimes it's the other way arround.

I need to capture and erase everything which is before one of these two variable, my actual regex is:

```
sed 's/.\+\(user_id=\\?\|product=\)//g'
```

But this code is not working, it will always select everything behind the second element.
In my exemple it will retrieve:

```
sdk_version=ios4.2.4&gender=male&product=JE779SPAKLZ5SGAMZ&shop_country=sg&user_id=
```

instead of:

```
sdk_version=ios4.2.4&gender=male&product=
```

This regex works here: http://regexr.com/3beh2

but impossible to make it work with sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break it down into the two scenarios that can happen. **product** followed by **user_id** or **user_id** followed by **product**.

```
sed -e '/.*product=.*user_id=.*/{s/.*product=//}' -e '/.*user_id.*product=.*/{s/.*user_id=//}'
```

The last `-e` could be reduced to just `'/.*product=.*/{s/.*user_id=//}'` as if the first command was successful then there will be no **product**.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non-greedy quantifier in Perl:

```
 perl -pe 's/^.*?(product|user_id)=//'
 #              ^
 #              |
 #   match as little as possible
```

Comment: @user3636476: sed doesn't have the feature. Switch to Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with sed requires a little trickery because sed does not support non-greedy matching. The simplest way to do it, I think, is

```
sed 's/\(user_id=\\?\|product=\)/\n&/; s/.*\n//'
```

This falls into two parts:

```
s/\(user_id=\\?\|product=\)/\n&/   # Place a newline before the first matching
                                   # foo=bar token as a marker
s/.*\n//                           # Remove everything up to the newline
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\&user_id=/\
&/
     s/.*\&\(product=.*\)\n/\1/
     s/.*\n\&//'
```

- posix sed version
- assume `user_id`  and `product` are preceeded by `&`